# Why does GAE dev server takes several minutes to start?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

The google app engine development server is taking a very long time to start up (10+ minutes). During startup GAE spends a lot of time in autoreload.py and ProtocolBuffer.py.  Any idea why it is taking so long? What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: Which SDK? (Java/Go/Python)

Comment: I think ProtocolBuffer.py is getting called from the TryMerge (line 2427) function in entity_pb.py.  It is inside this loop for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a very large amount of data in my local datastore.  It was bogging down the startup process.  I cleared my local datastore and now it is starting up quickly.

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore myapp
```